# Where is krb5_util on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: apt, kerberos

The crucial `krb5_util` command (http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/admin_commands/kdb5_util.html#kdb5-util-8) doesn't seem to be available on Ubuntu 14.04 although it ships with 1.12.x and it is availabel in the installation from sources (1.12.1-final).

`apt-file update && apt-file find krb5_util` doesn't give me anything.

`krb5_newrealm` (which doesn't seem to exist in sources installation) doesn't have any arguments according to the manpage and ignores it's `--help` argument.

Could it be that Ubuntu does a really strange packaging for Kerberos which should be documented much better (or at least mentioned (in manpages, usage hints, etc.))?

I installed `krb5-config`, `krb5-doc`, `krb5-user`, `krb5-kdc` and `krb5-admin-server` in `synaptic`.

Background is that I want to setup an OpenAFS with Kerberos.

Comment: Ubuntu documentation is here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kerberos How did you install Kerberos ?

Comment: This wiki article is consitent with the available binaries on Ubuntu, but not usable with the official Kerberos documentation (http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/). Both are missing information information about commands the other is mentioning (Ubuntu wiki doesn't talk about `krb5_util`, Kerberos docs not about `krb5_newrealm`). My problem is that I don't understand this mess for distributions of the same version of a software.

Comment: It seems most distros package and manage kerberos is slightly different ways. In ubuntu , krb5_newrealm calls krb5_util with ubuntu specific options. I am not sure about the details mind you as I am more familiar with kerberos on Fedora and RHEL. It is a somewhat similar situation with Apache. At any rate, you are always better off starting with distro specific guides .

Comment: need to install `libkrb5-3` to install `krb5`.

Comment: Have you checked the `krb5-kdc` package? Also, it's `kdb5_util`, not `krb5_util`.

Comment: I just saw that, too! `kdb5_util` is in `krb5-kdc`. But the sense of `krb5_newrealm` stays unclear...

Comment: [This](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/krb5/trusty/view/head:/debian/krb5_newrealm) (Debian version [here](http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=pkg-k5-afs/debian-krb5-2013.git;a=blob;f=debian/krb5_newrealm;h=b9da0195c915ccbe8f7a3186cd568155ca3d2c9e;hb=HEAD)) is the file. It seems that it's mainly for setting up Kerberos in a new environment. EDIT: [here's](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/krb5/trusty/view/head:/debian/krb5_newrealm.sgml) the equivalent man page.